# How do you code a Tweedie distribution in JAGS/BUGS?

Tags: r, jags, tweedie

I'd like to run a model on a Tweedie distributed variable using JAGS through R. I know that JAGS doesn't have a Tweedie distribution as standard, but that it is possible to specify one as a compound Gamma/Poisson. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to code it in JAGS. I wrote the below based on code scavenged from various sources to simply try and recover the mean, power and phi parameters from a Tweedie random variable. It doesn't run at the moment because of invalid parent values on y, presumably because y[i] appears on the right hand side and left hand side of an expression. This is as it was written in the source code, but I'm evidently misusing it. Any pointers on how to properly specify this distribution would be much appreciated and probably of wider use as I haven't been able to find any simple coded on examples on how to set up Tweedie models in JAGS.

```
y = mgcv::rTweedie(mu=rep(2,100),p=1.33,phi=1)

jags_data = list(y=y,n=length(y))

jags_model = 
 "model{
    
    for (i in 1:n) {
      lambda[i] <- pow(mu,2-p)/(phi *(2-p))
      num[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
      shape[i,1] <- num[i]*((2-p)/(p-1))
      rate[i,1] <- 1/(phi*(p-1)*pow(mu,p-1))
      shape[i,2] <- 1
      rate[i,2] <- exp(-lambda[i])
      # Takes shape/rate parameter 1 if y > 0 and 2 if y = 0
      y[i] ~ dgamma(shape[i,1+equals(y[i],0)],rate[i,1+equals(y[i],0)]) 
    }
    
    mu    ~ dunif(0,100)
    p     ~ dunif(1,2)  ## Tweedie power parameter
    phi   ~ dunif(0,30) ## Dispersion parameter
    
  }
  
  "

model_file = tempfile(fileext = 'txt')
writeLines(jags_model,model_file)

jm = rjags::jags.model(
  file = model_file,
  data = jags_data,
  n.chains = 3,
  n.adapt = 1500
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to function.  Whether it "worked" or not seems like more of an open question, but the posterior means of the parameters are pretty close to the true values.  I did this in R with `runjags`, but all of the pieces are here to be done in JAGS independent of R.

First, I generated the data and also put the shape matrix in the data with a column of NA values so they could be overwritten in each iteration of the simulation.  I also added a variable called `yind` which is 2 if `y == 0` and 1 otherwise.  This will serve as the value that will index the `shape` and `rate` matrices.  It is probably more efficient to do this in the data rather than have JAGS evaluate and `equals()` function a few times in every iteration for every value of `y` which are fixed at the beginning.

```
y = mgcv::rTweedie(mu=rep(2,100),p=1.33,phi=1)
shape_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(y), ncol=2)
shape_mat[,2] <- 1
jags_data = list(y=y,n=length(y), yind = 2-(y > 0), shape = shape_mat)
```

Next, the model is the same save the change in how the shape matrix is dealt with and the addition of `yind`.

```
jags_model = 
  "model{
    
    for (i in 1:n) {
      lambda[i] <- pow(mu,2-p)/(phi *(2-p))
      num[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
      shape[i,1] <- num[i]*((2-p)/(p-1))
      rate[i,1] <- 1/(phi*(p-1)*pow(mu,p-1))
      ## moved to data
      # shape[i,2] <- 1
      rate[i,2] <- exp(-lambda[i])
      # Takes shape/rate parameter 1 if y > 0 and 2 if y = 0
      y[i] ~ dgamma(shape[i,yind[i]],rate[i,yind[i]]) 
    }
    
    mu    ~ dunif(0,100)
    p     ~ dunif(1,2)  ## Tweedie power parameter
    phi   ~ dunif(0,30) ## Dispersion parameter
    
  }
  "
```

The invalid parent values likely came from the initial values.  The `num` poisson draws have to be consistent with `lambda`, which is a function of `mu`, `p` and `phi`.  So, the initial values are important to ensure that these are all consistent.  I set the three model parameters to the values below and then calculated `lambda`.  I set `num` to the nearest integer value to `lambda` based on the values of these three parameters.

```
inits <- list(mu = 5, p=1.5, phi=5,  
              num = rep(1, length(y)))
```

Next, I ran the model and summarized:

```
library(runjags)
out <- run.jags(model=jags_model, data = jags_data, monitor=c("mu", "p", "phi"), burnin=5000, sample=10000, 
                inits = list(inits, inits), n.chains = 2, keep.jags.files=TRUE)
summary(out)
# Lower95   Median Upper95     Mean         SD Mode       MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff        AC.10     psrf
# mu  1.606100 1.921855 2.24793 1.927986 0.16489395   NA 0.001534324     0.9 11550 -0.006514202 1.000242
# p   1.252230 1.377415 1.50807 1.379773 0.06563517   NA 0.002049511     3.1  1026  0.354243967 1.013941
# phi 0.871354 1.098075 1.36870 1.109978 0.12874006   NA 0.003880090     3.0  1101  0.322202621 1.004731
```